# Attaching Issue in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, entity-framework

I create a stored procedure which returns a table (physically stored table).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspTest
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT * from Table1
END
```

When I capture the output using Entity Framework, it loads up the entity properly.

```
var output = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Table1>("dbo.uspTest").ToList<Table1>();
```

the "output" variable contains the data returned from SP but it this List of Table1 object doesn't not load up foreign key tables automatically.  I added below code to mitigate this problem

```
foreach (var member in output)
{
   entities.Table1s.Attach(member);
}
```

After attaching each entity all child tables are linked for each Table1 member.  But, when I come back to this same method second time, it gives me an error failing to attach.

```
Attaching an entity of type 'Table1' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.
```

i tried setting the state of entity to detached but of no luck!! Does anyone have any clue what i should do here?

I'm using Database first approach.

Comment: Search for "Entity Framework Lazy Loading" .. or look up the Include command in Linq.

Comment: stored procedure results don't have foreign keys. tables have them. your stored proc should return everything you need and nothing else. if you need more things, you should be using linq and includes to get attached objects.

Comment: Do you know what 'Attach' method is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of [`Database.SqlQuery<TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx) are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type. If you want the returned entities are tracked by the context, then you should use [`DbSet<TEntity>.SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696332(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

```
var output = entities.Table1s.SqlQuery("dbo.uspTest").ToList();
```

This way you don't need to use extra code to attach the entities.

But, why do you want to access to the `Table1` using a SP when you already have the `DBSet<Table1> Table1s`?. I guess you have a more complex stored procedure and you did this to explain your issue, but if that is your SP, as @DLeh commented above, you should use [Linq to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Perfect!! This is what I'm looking for.  I never realized there is SqlQuery on entity as well.  I thought it was available only at Database level.  Thanks for your solution.  You are right - I have a complex SP which returns a set of data on top of which I need to track it using EF to ensure proper data is displayed on UI.  All solved with your solution.

Comment: No problem ;). Happy for having helped you