# Stored procedure in Entity Framework doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have two models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Draw your attention User class contain:

```
public Role Role { get; set; }
```

If I use this code:

```
User user = db.Users.Include(u => u.Role).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == model.UserId);
```

It works fine, returns `User` with `Role`.

Then I check the EF generated SQL query, it looks like this:

```
@UserID int
AS
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id],  
    [Limit1].[Email] AS [Email],
    [Limit1].[Password] AS [Password],
    [Limit1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
    [Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM  
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
         [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
         [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
         [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
         [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
         [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
         [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
     FROM  
         [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
     INNER JOIN 
         [dbo].[Roles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RoleId] = [Extent2].[Id]
     WHERE 
         [Extent1].[UserID] = @UserID) AS [Limit1]
END
```

I copied this SQL and created a stored procedure, testing in SQL Server Management Studio, it works perfectly.

Then I using my stored procedure, C# code:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserId);
var U = Database.SqlQuery<User>("User_GetUserWithRole @UserID", param);
```

And then there is a problem, U contain Role = null. Why?

Comment: use `db.Users.SqlQuery("your procedure").ToList();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attaching Issue in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632387/attaching-issue-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @techspider `.ToList()` doesn't help

Comment: It is not just `ToList()`. pay close attention to it; `SqlQuery` is executed on `entity` instead of `Database`

Comment: please pay close attention to my suggestion provided initially; entity doesn't mean to look for entity in your code;

Comment: @techspider `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserId);
var U = Users.SqlQuery("User_GetUserWithRole @UserID", param).toList();` If I understand you correctly... But it doesn't help P.S. 
Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

`Database.SqlQuery` does not populate navigation properties.

There's a manual workaround for this which is to attach the entity to context and load the property. However this results in multiple queries back to the DB so not really recommended.

From memory it's something like this:

```
foreach(var user in U)
{
    context.Attach(user);
}
```